# Access Kubernetes Dashboard Via HTTP Instead of HTTPS

Tags: kubernetes, microk8s

*Question*

How can I enable HTTP requests? I have a primary web server that is a proxy and sends HTTP requests to the MicroK8S server but cannot due to the HTTP error.

Install command used:

```
sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.23/stable
```

Infrastructure

```
Self-Hosted on a virtual machine locally
```

*Problem*

I have a MicroK8S server setup using this command: `microk8s enable dashboard dns registry istio`

I have also edited the dashboard service as such (replaced clusterip with nodeport)

*kubernetes-dashboard service*

[image]

[image]

*Result*

I can navigate to the kubernetes-dashboard by going to https://IP:30051/ of the server (yes, requests using SSL work). However if I try to use HTTP instead of HTTPS I get the following error message.

`Client sent an HTTP request to an HTTPS server.`

Comment: Please provide more information about your current setup - which Kubernetes version are you using, which solution did you use to setup a cluster (kubeadm or some cloud provider solution etc.).

Comment: @Bazhikov provided the requested updates. However, the process for allowing HTTP for the dashboard I imagine would be the same regardless of version.

Answer (score 2):

Answered in Slack, the default addon doesn't pass `--insecure-bind-address` so the insecure port is accessible only on localhost: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/b5103f61175a10d6b066eeb3ef603263f9b61bd4/cluster/addons/dashboard/dashboard.yaml#L195-L196

You can find all options documented here: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/1148f7ba9f9eadd719e53fa3bc8bde5b7cfdb395/docs/common/dashboard-arguments.md#arguments

If you add `--insecure-bind-address=0.0.0.0` to the CLI options and switch your service to port 9090 then you can use HTTP instead.

But also just don't do this, it's a bad and unsafe idea.

Comment: There is a login-not-available error when using HTTP. How do I get around this?
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard/README.md#login-not-available